# What does `void f(void())` mean?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Consider the following snippet:

```
void f(void());
```

What does that `void()` as an argument type mean exactly?
If it's (as it probably is) a function pointer or function reference, is it legal code?

As far as I know, I cannot define a function pointer as:

```
void(f)() = &g;
```

Why should it be accepted when dealing with functions' parameters?

Comment: It's always a pleasure to share something that I've not been able to find on this site, then receive downvotes without comments and decide to delete the question. I'll be back the first time one will ask the same. No problem.

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to undelete this. Completely understand your decision, and I can't make any calls about the accuracy of the question and answer because I don't know C++, but we need to get people over the stigma associated with self-answering. Your call.

Comment: @undo Let's see if it's worth still sticking with self-answered question. I would say no anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It puzzled me for a while the first time I encountered it.

I was already accustomed to the fact that the functions below have the same type:

```
void f(int[]);
void f(int*);
```

Something similar applies in case of function pointers.

As mentioned in [*dcl.fct*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#5) of the working draft (emphasis mine):

> The type of a function is determined using the following rules. [...] After determining the type of each parameter, **any parameter** of type “array of T” or **of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”**. [...]

Because of that, the following function:

```
void f(void());
```

Has the same type of:

```
void f(void(*)());
```

Thus the definitions below are identical:

```
void f(void(g)());
void f(void(*g)());
```

Comment: [As I said to @undo in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39440970/4987285), it's always a pleasure (unfortunately, ironically) to share knowledge on SO. At least a comment for the downvote would help knowing what's wrong with this answer and improve it. Well, anyway, I think it's a losing battle.